# How to align elements of a list group?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a layout like this:

Big screens:

```
A1 B1      C1
-------------
A2 B2      C2
```

Small screens:

```
A1  C1
B1
------
A2  C2
B2
```

(A, B, C) together are a single list-group-item.
A should be all the way to the left, C all the way to the right at the same height as A, and B right next to A if there's space, else below.

I tried alignment using align-top and using a container, but I couldn't get it to work.

This is my current approach https://jsfiddle.net/keineahnung/wafkj29b/, but it doesn't quite work as I want it to.

When breaking A/B, C moves down a bit, it doesn't stay on the same height as A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the grid columns in each list group item. This way you position and order the items as desired.

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="row no-gutters w-100">
        <div class="col-auto pr-3">12:00 - 13:00</div>
        <div class="col-md order-last order-md-0">
            <span class="text-nowrap">
                <span class="badge-pill badge-primary text-nowrap">Tag 1</span> <span class="badge-pill badge-primary ml-2 text-nowrap">Tag 2</span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto ml-auto">01:00</div>
    </div>
 </a>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/rjTIU6ON98

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! How do I change the point at which the tags get moved below the time?

Comment: You would change the 'md` breakpoint on `col-md order-last order-md-0`. For example, `col-sm order-last order-sm-0` would make it occur at a smaller screen width.